# Minimum install of SQL Server 2008 required to able to run bcp

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I need to run bcp.exe on a client machine which has no SQL Server 2008 installed. Does anyone know the minimum install options I need to select to get the bcp tool? I tried 'Client Tools Connectivity' but that didn't include it.

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to select "Management Tools - Basic" when installing SQL Server 2008 to get bcp

Answer (score 0):

I have installed "Management Tools - Basic" on my instance of SQL Srv 2008, but bcp still does not run. Is there any configuration that has to be done after installing this feature??